# Create grouping variable based on names of data frame column

Tags: r

I have a `DF` with column of names

```
DF
a     b
a.b   1
a.c   2
a.d   3
b.c   4
b.l   5
b.d   6
c.a   6
c.b   7
```

I need to create new column which contains symbol before `.` in `DF$a`, so that

```
DF
    a     b   c
    a.b   1   a
    a.c   2   a
    a.d   3   a
    b.c   4   b
    b.l   5   b
    b.d   6   b
    c.a   6   c
    c.b   7   c
```

Is it possible? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: not as elegant as akrun's solution, but this will work too. `DF$c <- sapply(as.character(DF$a), function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,"[.]"))[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the dot character(`\\.`) followed by one or more characters to the end of the string and replace with `''`.

```
DF$c <- sub("\\..*$", "", DF$a)
DF$c
#[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(DF$a, "\\w+")
```